# How do I fix a 1.8.3 crash on a laptop?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

OK, so I'm helping a kid to re-install Minecraft on his laptop. He doesnt have any mods, any resource packs or anything else. Whenever I try to launch Minecraft it shows this:

```
 ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I let you down. Sorry :(

Time: 2/26/15 12:22 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at avf.ap(SourceFile:534)
    at avf.am(SourceFile:363)
    at avf.a(SourceFile:310)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at avf.ap(SourceFile:534)
    at avf.am(SourceFile:363)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at avf.a(SourceFile:310)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8.3
    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
    CPU: 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P7350 @ 2.00GHz
    Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 60847904 bytes (58 MB) / 160829440 bytes (153 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.8.3
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
```

Is this normal? Pls help me. The kid will be here the next day!

Comment: Your version of Java might be the issue. Try reverting back to Java 7

Comment: It appears to be a problem between Minecraft and the graphics driver. If you've just done a complete reinstall of this computer's OS and such, it might still be running generic video drivers that are fine for starting up, but inadequate for heavy 3D games like Minecraft. See about updating the graphics drivers. Alternatively, if you've *changed* operating systems (say, going from Win7 to Win8), proper 3D graphics drivers may not be available.

Comment: O_O wut? Uh ok, yeah. i forgot to tell you. im actually 13 so...

Comment: Has your friend been able to play Minecraft 1.8.3 in the past? If not, or you don't know, try setting the game version to 1.7.2 and try with that. You can set the game version by clicking "Edit Profile" in the Launcher.

Comment: As for the graphics card stuff that SevenSidedDie mentioned, there is a help page related to this problem that has instruction on how to check for drivers at http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/pixel-format-not-accelerated/

Comment: What is your computer's model? Intel Series 4 Chipset and earlier will be unable to run Minecraft. When you start up 1.7, does the main menu display the message that your graphics drivers are outdated and you need to upgrade to OpenGL 2.1?

Comment: It looks like there's an OpenGL error. You may want to try updating the graphics drivers. What GPU does the laptop have?

Comment: @tuxedoandex by the error code, it says his processor is a Core 2 Duo P7350. So, I'd imagine that it comes with Intel 965/960 Graphics Media Accelerator chipset.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the technical support article

http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/pixel-format-not-accelerated/